# Declaring a Function with generics to use as value in a lookup map

Tags: java, generics, lambda, functional-interface

I'm doing something wrong but not sure what.
Trying to make a lookup map that provides me functions I can call on.

Simple demonstration of the problem:

aa.java

```
public class aa { /** doesn't matter for this example */}
```

ab.java

```
public class ab extends aa { /** doesn't matter for this example */}
```

Helper.java

```
public static short[] convert(ab foo)
{
  //doesn't matter but eventually returns a short[] i.e.
  return new short[5];
}

private interface aaConverterI
{
  public <T extends aa> short[] method(Function<T, short[]> in);
}

private static Map<String, aaConverterI> bar = new HashMap<>();
static
{
  bar.put("blah", Helper::convert);
}
```

Compiler says `The type Helper does not define convert(Function<T, short[]>) that is applicable here` on the Helper::convert, `The method put(String, Helper.aaConverterI) in the type Map<String, aaConverterI> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Helper::convert)`.

If I add a

```
static Function<ab, short[]> blahFunction = Helper::convert;
```

There is no complaints about that, and I can change the put to

```
bar.put("blah", blahFunction);
```

Which then makes the compiler just complain on the put that `The method put(String, Helper.aaConverterI) in the type Map<String, Helper.aaConverterI> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Function<ab, short[]>)`.

I'm missing something but I'm not sure what.  Tried adding a `@FunctionalInterface` to convert declaration and that didn't change anything.

What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think the generics you've specified on `aaConverterI` do what you think they do.

Comment: Oh quite possibly @LouisWasserman. What I am trying to say is any class that extends aa should be a valid input, and I have a bunch of them.  and Helper has a method for each one where that class goes in and out comes a short[].  That method is in Helper because I don't have authorship over those other classes.  I'm trying to make a map I can use so I can use it as in a lookup method that has as input any of the classes instantiated and have it give me the array back (the String is the object name which follows a predictable pattern).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This interface:

> ```
> private interface aaConverterI
> {
>   public <T extends aa> short[] method(Function<T, short[]> in);
> }
> ```

... satisfies the requirements for use as a functional interface.  For a method reference to be compatible with this functional interface, its signature must match that of `aaConverterI.method()`.  That is, it accepts a matching `Function` as its argument and returns a `short[]`.

This:

> ```
> public static short[] convert(ab foo)
> ```

... *does not* have such a signature.  It accepts an argument of type `ab`, which is not a `Function`, all other considerations notwithstanding.  That explains your error.

---

I suspect you meant to define `aaConverterI` more like this:

```
private interface aaConverterI
{
  public <T extends aa> short[] method(T in);
}
```

... but even that does not work.  `aaConverterI.method()` can accept an argument of type `aa` or any of its subtypes, but `Helper.convert()` cannot accept an argument of type `aa` (for example).  Note too that `aaConverter.method()` is not actually getting anything useful out of its type parameterization.  You might as well just perform the erasure manually if that's what you really wanted.

Another, more likely alternative would involve making the interface generic instead of the method:

```
private interface aaConverterI<T extends aa>
{
  public short[] method(T in);
}
```

... then you could write:

```
private static Map<String, aaConverterI<? extends aa>> bar = new HashMap<>();
static
{
  bar.put("blah", Helper::convert);
}
```

, but that probably *still* doesn't help you, because you will find that there is no typesafe way to use any of the methods you pull back out of that map.

**Bottom line:**

Java generics are not powerful enough to parameterize the `Map` you would really like to define, where the keys are (say) `Class<?>` and the values are type `aaConverterI<the-type-corresponding-to-the-key>`.  Your best bet probably is, in fact, the manual erasure:

```
private interface aaConverterI
{
  public short[] method(aa in);
}
```

, where you write all your converter methods with that exact signature and, yes, cast or `Class.cast()` within.

Comment: I see yes that first definition is what I had in mind now that I read it but I see what you mean by the rest of it.   My basic problem is that I have external code I can't alter that I'm trying to use generics to get around very repetitive boilerplate I have to use to access the data that lives in those classes.  Your answer fully explains why that's not possible in this manner (My first attempt was to parametrize the whole thing which failed since the return values are arrays of primitives). Thank you!

Comment: *`My basic problem is that I have external code I can't alter that I'm trying to use generics to get around very repetitive boilerplate I have to use to access the data that lives in those classes.`*  Sometimes it helps to provide a use case to show with a simple example of what you really need to do.  Then another alternative may be available.  BTW, I recently asked an OP for a use case as I thought it might be an XY problem.  The OP took great offense and starting slinging pejoratives.   This is just one way we try and help folks.  No offense is intended.

Comment: Oh no offense taken or intended.  I can't post the code I'm working with for security reasons, so I use things like foo, bar, blah, etc...

Comment: Yeah I understand.  What I meant was, a made up example (Perhaps a [mre]) of what you  presently need to do in terms of `repetiveness` vs what you want to do to simplify things.  But then, that may just be too complicated.

Comment: I have dozens of methods that look like following
```
public static javaprimitive[] getFromCppArray_cppstlprimitive_Size(cppstlprimitiveArraySize arrayIn)
{
  int size = Size;
  javaprimitive[] retval = new javaprimitive[size];
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    retval[i] = arrayIn.get(i);
  }
  return retval;
}
```

javaprimitive is things like Java byte, short, int, long, etc... or even java.math.BigInteger.

Size is a positive Integer like 5 or 5000 or whatever.  
cppstlprimitive is things like std::uint8_t

Comment: cppstlprimitiveArraySize is a class spun up by SWIG parsing through a bunch of C++ code I have no authorship over.  It's a whole bunch of nearly identical looking classes that give me access to C++ std::array datasets in this C++ code I'm talking about.  I was able to declare a local class in Java (the equivalent of aa in my earlier example above) and tell SWIG to make all cppstlprimitiveArraySize extend that same parent class, and I think I can add other customization via instructions to SWIG but I'm not sure what would help. 
There is lots of permutations of all of the above + setters too!